# Datediff function in hive

Tags: hive

Regarding `DateDiff` function

```
select datediff(current_date, '-2018-01-21');
```

what is `-` here as I know `datediff(enddata,startdate)`

if we mention minus for `startdate` it getting number values `1474138`

can please help to understand

Comment: select datediff(to_date('2018-03-22'), to_date('-2018-03-11')); --1474146 --10
select datediff(current_date, '2018-03-01'); --1473780  --1
select datediff(current_date, '-2018-01-21'); --1473780  --2
1474138 --Feb-28
1474139 --Feb-27
1474140 --Feb-26
1474141 --Feb-25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query confirms that a negative date is similar to a negative integer.  If you subtract a negative number to a positive number, it is the same as adding their absolute values (ignoring the signs).  For example; 8 - (-4) = 8 + 4

Thus, since the minimum date value for date type is '0000-01-01', we measure the number of days from year -2018 to 0000 and add to the number of days from 0000 to 2018. Then, we get 1474137 ( = 737122 + 737015). Hope this helps. Thanks.

```
Query:
    select datediff('2018-03-02', '0000-01-01'), datediff('0000-01-01', '-2018-03-01'), datediff('2018-03-02', '-2018-03-01')
Result:
        737122   737015   1474137
```

Again, 737122 + 737015 = 1474137. There are 1474137 days since 2018-Mar-01 BC.

Comment: If you like my answer please accept it by clicking the accept button. Thanks.

Comment: The accept button is below the inverted triangle across my answer. It is also looks like a check.